# Is it possible to do mutual ssl authentication on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku

I have an app developed in rails that is hosted at Heroku. What I want to do is set up mutual ssl authentication, in order to verify that data is coming from an approved source. Heroku's guidelines don't seem to mention anything about this, and googling the topic gives somewhat old results stating that it is simply not possible.

So my question is; is it possible to do mutual ssl authentication on Heroku? Is there a way to check the certificate of the incoming connection?

Comment: for anyone finding this and wondering about the answer, the answer is no, Heroku does not support mutual ssl authentication. In order to do this you would need to verify the certificate of the client, which heroku does not support (and as you have no access to the routing layer, you cant change that). see https://help.heroku.com/3NTWIMNK/does-heroku-support-client-side-ssl-connections-a-k-a-two-way-authentication.

Comment: An alternate solution would be to set up a server for the client to connect to, which does the two way authentication and then in turn connects to heroku. All transmissions would then go through this external server first.

Comment: Suppose you're not trying to BUILD a certificate based mutual authentication application but only trying to USE a third parties mutual authentication system in heroku. Is this possible? Where would you store the certificate since you cant manage the Trust/Key store?